# It is always possible to construct continuous function?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

Given $D \subset X \subset \mathbb R$, I want to create a function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that

(1) it's continuous

(2) it has fixed value for every element of D (different values)

When it is possible?

For example, if D is finite, is certainly possible (with a polynomial, for example). It is possible even if $D = \mathbb N$ and, for example, I want that f(n) = n for every $n \in \mathbb N$. Or it is possible for every D if I fixed a *single* value for every element.

It's (obviously) not possible if I choose $D = \mathbb R$ and I set the values such that the function is discontinuous. It's also not possible if I choose $D = \{x_n\}$ with $x_0 = 0, x_1=0.9, x_2=0.99 ... x_n \rightarrow 1$ and I set $f(x_n) = n$, in fact $f(1) = lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n) = \infty$ (it would be continuous in [0, 1)?)

I think it is a well-known question, but I don't know how to search it.

Thanks in advance.

(edit: and what if I work in a generic topological space, not $\mathbb R$?)

Comment: Relevant result: the Tietze extension theorem applies if $D$ is relatively closed in $X$ since any subspace $X$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is $T_4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible as long as it's not obviously impossible. That is, as long as there aren't two convergent sequences $x_n, y_n$ in $D$ (with limits not necessarily in $D$) such that $\lim x_n = \lim y_n$ but either one of $f(x_n)$ or $f(y_n)$ doesn't converge or $\lim f(x_n)\neq \lim f(y_n)$ (where $f$ is the function we're trying to extend to a continuous function on $\mathbb R$).

To see this, simply define $f(x)=\lim f(x_n)$ on $\overline D$, where $x_n\to x$ is a sequence in $D$. By our assumption this is a valid definition, and it extends $f$ continuously to a closed set. [Any continuous function on a closed set can be extended to $\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301773/extension-of-continuous-function-on-a-closed-subset-of-mathbbr).

This may not work in other metric spaces, or even in $\mathbb R^n$, since the linked proof relies on a very one-dimensional specific property of open sets. It works in any metric space in which continuous functions on closed sets can always be extended. Such spaces are the subject of the [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) (thanks Daniel Schepler in the comments).

Comment: It should just be sufficient to require $(f(x_n))_{n=1}^\infty$ converges whenever $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ does.  Then it implies your condition: if $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to x$ also, then by constructing the sequence interleaving $x_n$ and $y_n$, if $f$ applied to that sequence has a limit, then the limits of $f(x_n)$ and $f(y_n)$ are equal.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Wow, awesome! Didn't think of that.