# Extension of continuous functions on closed set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $F\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a closed set, and $f:F\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Show that there is a function $g$ defined and continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for each $x\in F$.

The hint is telling that since $F^c$ is open, it's composed of a countable collection of disjoint open intervals, noted as $\bigcup_k (a_k,b_k)$. Then take $g$ to be linear in each of the intervals.

But I'm stuck when I'm try to prove $g$ is continuous considering the fact that a function separately continues on two sets may not continues on their unions. And I don't know how to apply the definition when every intervals like $(a_k-\delta,a_k)$ may contain points both in $F$ and $F^c$. So how should I deal with this problem?

Comment: if you can just show that $F$ is actually a bounded interval, then you can simply "attach" any continuous function at each endpoints so that $g$ is continuous at $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra I don't think $F$ is definitely an interval , it may be some single points.

Comment: How about dividing into two cases? First case is something like the characteristic function over rational numbers (possibly infinitely many points over zero measure set) whereas the other case is simply something similar to characteristic function over irrational numbers.

Not sure if this helps... Good luck!

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301773/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Well, thanks for answering. But I've already how to construct $g$ but feel difficult to prove it's continuous, it's really not that obvious for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_0 \in F^c$ then $g$ is linear in a neighborhood of $x_0$ and therefore continuous at $x_0$.

The more interesting case is to prove continuity at a point $x_0 \in F$: Given $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in F$ with $|x-x_0 |< \delta$. Now we consider two cases:

*Case 1:* The open interval $(x_0, x_0 + \epsilon)$ does not contain any point from the set $F$. In that case is $g$  linear on $(x_0, x_0 + \epsilon)$ with $\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x) = f(x_0) = g(x_0)$.

*Case 2:* There is a $ x_1 \in (x_0, x_0 + \epsilon) \cap F$. For every $x \in (x_0, x_1)$ is $g(x) $ either equal to $f(x)$, or a value between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ with $x_0 \le a < x < b \le x_1$. In both cases is $|g(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

This shows that $g$ is right-continuous at $x_0$. In the same way one can show that $g$ is left-continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: Case 1 needs the result that open intervals are connected in $\mathbb{R}$, imho.

Comment: @RomandadeGore: All intervals are connected, but at which point is that needed here? I currently do not see it, but I might miss something.

Comment: This guarantees that $(x_0,x_0 + \epsilon)$ lies in just one of the $(a_k,b_k)$, which gives a straightforward description of $g$. Of course, you will argue that this is evident, but I don't agree. In fact, showing that any point of $F$ either is interior to $F$ or is one of the $a_k,b_k$ is just the whole (always completely ignored) difficulty of the proof (and I would not know where to start with that).

Comment: @RomandadeGore: What we need (if I remember correctly after 1.5 years): 1) $F^c$ is  the countable union of disjoint open intervals $I_j$. 2) The endpoints of each $I_j$ are in $F$. 3) Every interval in $F^c$ is a subset of one of those intervals $I_j$. The last one is true because intervals are connected.