# Want to find a proof of the Extension Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Question: I am trying to find a proof of the following extension theorem:
If $E$ is a subset of $X$ where $E$ is closed, and $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then there exists $F:X\to\mathbb{R}$, continuous, such that $F$ restricted to $E$ is equal to $f$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Since this is an extension theorem, it seems like Google just wants to give me a million results on Caratheodory's theorem, and not this.

Thank you!

Comment: For $X = \mathbb{R}$ see [Extension of continuous function on a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301773/extension-of-continuous-function-on-a-closed-subset-of-mathbbr). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem ($\mathbb{R}$ is not the only normal space)

Comment: Although it's not exactly the same, this essentially amounts to the Tietze extension theorem. Google should be more helpful if you include Tietze's name.