# Extending a continuous $f$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, functions

Assume I have a continuous function $f$ on a closed set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$  that I would like **to extend** to a function $F$ on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

So Tietz Extension Theorem guarantees that such extension exists. See [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tietze_Extension_Theorem)

First of all, that function $f$ in the proof, is it a characteristic function of the main continuous function?

by defining for $t\notin C$:
$$
F(t)=\inf\Big\{f(s)+\frac{d(t,s)}{d(t,C)}-1: s\in C\Big\}
$$

Now assume continuous $f(s)$ defined on $[0,1]$ and let $t = 2$, then $d(2, [0,1]) = 1$, which value of $s$ would you plug in the formula to get the value of $F(t)$

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301773/extension-of-continuous-function-on-a-closed-subset-of-mathbbr?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Let $A$ be a closed subset of a metric space $X$ and $f:A→[0,1]$ be continuous. Let $F(x)=(1/(d(x,A)))\inf \{(1+f(y))d(x,y):y∈A\}-1$ for $x∈X\setminus A,F(x)=f(x)$ for $x∈A$. Then F is a continuous function from $X$ to $[0,1]$ which extends $f$.

Comment: I am not posting an answer because I am pretty sure this is  a duplicate.

Comment: There is also **Dugundji's extension theorem** which gives an explicit construction (using a suitable partion of unity of $\mathbb R^n\setminus C$) which depends **linearly and continuously** on the functions you want to extend (continuity with respect to the topology of uniform convergence on all compact sets). This works even for continuous functions with values in locally convex spaces.

Comment: Assume continuous $f(x)$ defined on $[0,1]$ and let $y = 2$, then $d(2, [0,1]) = 1$, which value of $x$ would you plug in the formula to get the value of $F(y)$

Comment: $F$ is not defined by a single value of $s$. It is the *infimum* of the values of the formula for all $s\in E$. (Except what is $E$? Did you mean $C$, the domain of $f$?) If $E$ is not closed, there is no reason to expect that there would be any $s$ where that infimum is taken on. Yes, because $C$ is closed, such an $s$ will exist, but that is not what is important. Consider in $\Bbb R^2$ with $C = \{(x,y)\mid x^2 + y^2 \ge 1\}$ the function $f((x,y)) = \frac x{|x|}$. What will be the value of $F((0,0))$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair How do we ensure that the extension $F$ of $f$ is continuous everywhere? Do we need to add further restrictions on its domain?

Comment: @PaulSinclair That's a bad example because $f$ is not continuous on $C$.

Comment: There is an issue (singularity) with dividing with $d(t,C)$. How to fix it while ensuring continuity?

Comment: @jjagmath - Dagnabbit! It should have been $\frac x{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$, but I appear to have confused myself along the way.

Comment: @PaulSinclair so are you telling me that there is no "unique" extension that would work for the whole space $X$.

Comment: There are an uncountable number of extensions to the whole space. This just isn't one of them. And the problem is not that dividing by $d(t,C)$ might be singular (it only would be if $t \in C$). The problem is that there are multiple points equally close to a point in the exterior ($0$ in this example), and the function has different values at them, which this method cannot handle.